# Database Architecture - dating site

Tags: database-design

I am developing a dating website that will be based on lots of personal fields that users will choose from a list. I have 43 different fields that the user must fill - each field has multiple answer options.

I have 3 options:

1. to build all of the site hardcoded and set all the fields and their options in the code - that will be difficult to maintain.
2. another option that I see now is to open a table for each field list and to fill it with its options.
3. to open one table for each field list and to save its name and its id and another table for the field options wich will include fields id , and the name of the options.

Those are the options I see - what will be the best way to go? Are there any other options I dont know of?

Comment: 3 option of having parent table for maintaining fields and child table for maintaining their options is better option.

Comment: If you're starting this type of project you should really do some reading on database design.  I'd recommend "Fundamentals of Database Systems" by Elmasri and Navathe.  Essentially though, it's going to need a database and not in code.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit your answer and remove option 1 it's so abhorrent a suggestion! Option 3 is your best option.

Comment: Paddy....same here...option 1 is so bad...i know i just wrote it here to show my opinion - hardcoded is worst way to go i would never do it - but what is the best way you advice?

Comment: Option 3 - with a table structure such as the one suggested by `Daniel Hilgarth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table "FIELDS" with ID and Name and a table "FIELD_OPTIONS" with an ID, the FIELD_ID and the Name of the option.

This would allow maximum flexibility.
For example, you could add a column "ALLOWS_MULTISELECT" to the "FIELDS" table to allow the selection of multiple options.

Comment: so that option 3...in this case my concern is for speed performances. that is a kind of a site that will have a huge database and the site needs to work fast

Comment: thank you , i will try to go with your suggestion and update you about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Create Base Tables of all fields that have drop down select options. Load select field options from those base tables.
Then make another table to save each person's data as a row of that table.
That person's data table will have column mapped with each field in your form.

Comment: I have 35 base tables .. that a lot of tables to load to a page...And i need this site to work fast - speed performance is everything in this case

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for you goals the best will be used document-oriented DB, like MongoDB,
Does using SQL are requirement ?

with document like:

```
{
"question": <>,
"answers": ["1","2","3","AA"],
"correct": "1"
}
```

Comment: YES i use SQL for this project so NOSQL is not an option:) do see any other way?

Comment: It is not about questions and answers. It is about attributes, like "Gender: Male, Female"

Comment: @DanielHilgarth its not difference answers or fields,

Comment: @Olga91 in case using SQL Daniel`s answer is good options, I agree with him